# Python re, how to capture 12"" / 14""

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I need to capture patterns like this one:

```
12"" / 14""
```

in

```
"Factory SP1 150 12"" / 14"""
```

The numbers change (always 2 digits), the rest doesn't.
Note that the double quotes at the ends of the string are part of the string and not enclosers.

Also note that I'm working with pandas and using `.str.extract(pattern)`.

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'filename.csv', delimiter = ';', usecols = ["OLD_COLUMN", "OTHER_COLUMNS"], encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False)

pattern = r'(\d{2}""\s*/\s*\d{2}"")'

df["NEW_COLUMN"] = df["OLD_COLUMN"].str.extract(pattern)
```

I changed groups, tried to escape every character. I can't find a way.

Comment: Your regex is good : https://regex101.com/r/GSkz95/1
I think if the extraction isn't good it's related to something else than the regex itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `r'\d{2}""\s*/\s*\d{2}""'` as regex:

```
s = '"Factory SP1 150 12"" / 14"""'
re.findall(r'\d{2}""\s*/\s*\d{2}""', s)
```

output:

```
['12"" / 14""']
```

Be careful with your strings: `"Factory SP1 150 12"" / 14"""` is equivalent to: `"Factory SP1 150 12" + " / 14" + ""` so `'Factory SP1 150 12 / 14'`

Comment: It doesn't work, pandas raises: 'ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups'. It seems to be something related to pandas, even though it uses python re module

Comment: @RiccardoLamera you did not provide a **pandas** input, here this is a simple string for pandas use `r'(\d{2}""\s*/\s*\d{2}"")'` as regex

Comment: Yes you're right. It doesn't find the pattern still. Could it be that 3rd double quote at the end the problem?

Comment: can you provide a real pandas example?

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = '([0-9]+""\s*/\s*[0-9]+"")'
```

Is a regex that will match that along with other expressions like `1351""/1""`. The issue is your use of the `r` or raw string. It causes your `\` in the pattern to be interpreted as literally `\`. So your original pattern would only match strings like `12\"\" / 14\"\"`